# can i have mic detection value in decibel range 0.0 to 120.0

Tags: iphone, avaudioplayer, decibel

Now I m using the class AVAudioPlayer .
But still i m not getting right value in decibel.
there is any way to get the value in decibel range 0.0 to 120.0 (not in -0.0 to -120).

if yes then plz tell me some body....

Answer (score 4):

0dB is, by general consensus, considered the maximum amplitude or SPL, so usually, amplitudes are given in negative decibels. Because decibels are a logarithmic unit (+10 dB means a factor of 2), you cannot define 0dB as 'silent' in any meaningful way.

Comment: i m not getting and this is not answer of my Question?

Comment: What I'm trying to tell you is that a 0 to 120 dB range doesn't make much sense. 0 dB is the loudest signal that can be played, recorded, or encoded without clipping. A 0 to 120 dB scale would thus correspond to signals ranging from full volume to 120 dB overdrive.

Read up on the definition of the dB unit and how it is generally used in signal processing.

What you're really looking for is a function to convert between decibels and linear amplification (in the 0 to 1 range, or 0 to 100%).